# Как определить вошедшего админа на PHP?

Tags: php

Доброго ПЯТНИЧНОГО времени суток. 8-)

Есть код простейшего входа для админа на сайт в админку:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();
}
else {
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
}
$query = "SELECT a23 FROM admin WHERE a22='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
$lst = @mysql_query($query);
    if (!$lst) {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();
}
    if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0) {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit(); 
}
$a23 = @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $a23['a23']) {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();
    }
}
```

Кривляться и врать не стану, честно выдернуто из какого-то обучающего пособия и переделано под свой лад. admin - таблица админов, a22 - логин, a23 - пароль.

---

Вопрос в следующем: как при входе админа определить, кто именно вошел? Допустим, в таблице админов у каждой записи есть "code". Вот этот "code" охота приравнять к какой-нибудь $admin.

Comment: вот это мазахизм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял то так. Хотя код у вас страшный.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\""); Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();

}else{
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    }

    $query = "SELECT a23,code FROM admin WHERE a22='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
    $lst = @mysql_query($query);

    $a23_passw= mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'a23' );
    $admin= mysql_result( $lst, 0, 'code' );

    if (!$lst)
    {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0)
    {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();
    }

    $a23 =  @mysql_fetch_array($lst);

    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $a23_passw)
    {
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать, ошибка в 16 строке ( $a23_passw = ... ). 

>`Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource.`

Вот думаю, что не так.

Comment: Проверьте, есть поля "a23" и "code" в таблице "admin". В таком ли они порядке идут? Или сначала "code" а потом "a23"?
Можно просто так сделать: 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE a22='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке, нет соединения с базой. С базой соединится не забыли?

Comment: Ну, до этого же, судя по всему, работало :)

Comment: Да. Забыл, думаю, вопрос решен. Спасибо.